# Two way checked binding in binding text (like computedObeservable)

Tags: knockout.js

I have to write and read the checked-binding of radiobuttons in different ways, like it is possible with a computedBinding. I don't want to mess up the ViewModel with ComputedObservables for every radiobutton. So I'm trying to control the binding out of the binding text in the markup. Perhaps it gets clearer with an example.

Example:
The user should be able to set a value with a unit. He can choose the unit and set the value. There a common values, which the user should be able to select (Radiobuttons). It should nevertheless be possible to write a specific value (input). Here is the markup (My itention is expressed through the "bindings" checked-read, cheacked-write).

```
<label><input type="radio" name="valuRadios" data-bind="text: ' 0.08' + unitValue().Unit().shortName() + ' ', checked-write: function (value) { value ? unitValue.Value(0.08) : null; }, checked-read: function () { return unitValue.Value() == 0.08 }" /></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="valuRadios" data-bind="text: ' 0.25' + unitValue().Unit().shortName() + ' ', checked-write: function (value) { value ? unitValue.Value(0.25) : null; }, checked-read: function () { return unitValue.Value() == 0.25 }" /></label>
...
<div class="input-append">
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: unitValue().Value">
   <span class="add-on" ata-bind="text: unitValue().Unit().shortName()"><span>
</div>
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `value` attribute on your radio inputs, then Knockout will set your observable based on it. From the example that you posted, I believe that you should be able to use the standard `checked` binding against an observable.  Something like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: values">
    <input type="radio" name="valuRadios" value="0.25" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $parent.myValue" />
    <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
</div>

<input data-bind="value: myValue" />

 <div data-bind="text: myValue"><div>
```

with JS of:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    values: [0.08, 0.025, 0.15],
    myValue: ko.observable(0.08)
});
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zPgwA/

If the scenario is a bit more complicated, then the strategy that I would use is to create a custom binding that generates a computed based on the original observable and then binds against the element with this new computed something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.specialChecked = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var original = valueAccessor();

        var filter = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                //return original() or some modified version of it
            },
            write: function(newValue) {
                //write to original(newValue) or modify newValue first
            },
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { checked: filter });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Ok its simpler than I thought. Also the strategy with the custom binding isn't needed in my situation, it is nevertheless a nice example. Thx. Maybe it will help me later.